# Angular - Unit Testing a promise in the construction of a component

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Assume the following component's constructor and function call:

```
constructor(private fooService: FooService){
    this.getBarFromService()
}

getBarFromService = () => fooService.getBar().then(bar => this.bar = bar)
```

And the service's crudely made `getBar()` function that should wait for an API result:

```
getBar() {
    let bar = null;
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.barBuilder.get('/bar').then(
            data => resolve(bar = data),             // data = baz
            error => reject(error)
        )
    return bar;
}
```

I now want to try and write a unit/integration test to determine that the component can request and display data without calling the API.
And from what I have read, I would need to mock the service so that it would not call `barBuilder` in reality and instead return a value right away. This resulted in the following test file:

```
beforeEach(() =>{
    let mockFooService = jasmine.createSpyObj('FooService', ['getBar']);
    mockFooService.getBar.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(baz))

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{provide: FooService, useValue: mockFooService}],
    }).compileComponents();
});

describe('get bar should return baz', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    component.getBar();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.bar).toBe(baz)
}
```

As the original `getBar()` function returns the data in a resolved promise object, instead of the data itself, I have to recreate said resolve, otherwise the test would fail saying that it cannot process the `then()` block of the call. Upon doing so, it gave me the idea that the test works on a functional level, as the test proceeds and I would assume the action in the `then()` block has been executed.

However, the value `baz` hasn't been applied to the component after the construction and a manual call, and there are no pointers to see where the mistake lies. Haphazardly throwing `console.log()` between each expectation shows that `component.bar` remains null on every point. I haven't found a plausible answer either, as using `fakeAsync` et cetera. does not apply, as the `getBarFromService()` function is not asynchronous itself.

Thus, I am at a loss, and the documentation of both Angular (v8) and Jasmine were followed down to the letter (the best I could, at that.)

The question rings; How would I be able to find why and where the variable `baz` is not applied to `component.bar` in the mock and/or the unit test itself, and how would I be able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `async()` and `whenStable()`

```
describe('get bar should return baz', async(() => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  component.getBar();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.bar).toBe(baz);
  });
}));
```

On a side note, your `getBar` can be drastically simplified to:

```
getBar() {
  return this.barBuilder.get('/bar');
}
```

the `.get` method already returns a promise. So no need to wrap it in a `new Promise`. If you want to have the bar variable inside your method, you can do this:

```
async getBar() {
  const bar = await this.barBuilder.get('/bar');

  return bar;
}
```

Comment: I did try `whenStable()` before, but apparently have done so wrongly, in the sense that `() => {}` shouldn't be in its own parentheses but in a `then()` block. thanks for the eye-opener! And yes, `getBar` could be simplified a lot, seems a bit strange to await a promise to a promise.